# Send ffmpeg segments to stdout so they can be processed by next pipe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shell, pipe

I have a pipeline like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -f matroska - |\
ffmpeg -i - -codec copy -map 0 -reset_timestamps 1 \
-segment_time 10 -f segment  output/out%03d.mov
```

which works and it is splitting the input video into 10 sec long segment files saved into output folder.
Now I would like to instead tell ffmpeg to pass them to stdout so in the next pipe I can hook up a script to decide what to do which each segment based on a presence of another file

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -f matroska - |\
ffmpeg -i - -codec copy -map 0 -reset_timestamps 1 \
-segment_time 10 -f segment |\
NEXT_PIPE_SCRIPT
```

The NEXT_PIPE_SCRIPT should be something like

```
{
TEST_FILE=".do"
if [ -f "$TEST_FILE" ]; then
     echo "$TEST_FILE exists going to redirect videos to a folder"
    >> output/$RANDOM.mov
 else 
    >> /dev/null
fi
}
```

The idea is that depends if the file is there or not
some segments should go to /dev/null and some to the output folder.

I am having troubles putting this all together.
Any help or suggestion much appreciated

Comment: What I was trying to do might be impossible as per this comment from 2017 https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-November/037718.html